# Format table of contents header to match section headers

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am trying to format my document to have the Table of Contents header look like all of my section headers. The section headers are centered and a different font size that what I can get with the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test Thesis}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\section*{\centering{Abstract}}
\lipsum

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Background}
\section*{\centering{Background}}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

In this example the Table of Contents is centered, but the exact same code in my actual document does not center it. It is also still too big.

*edit: working MWE

Comment: You code is broken. Please try to show a minimal working example.

Comment: Sorry, working to fix that now. Will edit the post with a MWE shortly.

Comment: I think, nut may very well be mistaken, that the ToC etc uses the subsection heading stylr.

Comment: When you edit/change your question please indicate what you have done. Someone might answer your original question while somebody else will have a go at your revised question.

Comment: report uses \chapter as first heading level. Why don't you use the article class if you want only sections?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought that Table of Contents only worked in `\documentclass{report}`. Changing it to `\documentclass{article}` fixed my problem. Thank you all for your help.